# bidimentional array is not printing values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Need help with this array, everything works fine excpt the last line im not getting the values on `$data[5][1] + $data[1][2] - $data[2][2]` ,

```
$data = array(
    array("Concepto","Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril"),
    array("Ingresos",100,       100,    100,    100),
    array("Egresos",200,        200,    200,    200),
    array("Deudores",300,       300,    300,    300),
);

$aa = array("Saldo",($data[1][1]-$data[2][1]),($data[1][2]-$data[2][2]),($data[1][3]-$data[2][3]),$data[1][4]-$data[2][4]);
array_push($data,$aa);
$bb = array("Saldo Acumulado",(5000)+($data[1][1])-$data[2][1],
            $data[5][1] + $data[1][2] - $data[2][2],
            "3",
            "4");
array_push($data,$bb);

$tblCuatrimestre1 = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
foreach($data as $dat){
      $tblCuatrimestre1 .= ' <tr>
        <td width="20%">'.$dat[0].'</td>
        <td width="20%">'.$dat[1].'</td>
        <td width="20%">'.$dat[2].'</td>
        <td width="20%">'.$dat[3].'</td>
        <td width="20%">'.$dat[4].'</td>
        <td width="20%">'.$dat[5].'</td>
      </tr>';
}
$tblCuatrimestre1 .= '</table>';
echo $tblCuatrimestre1;
```

Comment: the correct value of $data[5][1] + $data[1][2] - $data[2][2], should be 4800

Comment: You don't have 5th index of $data. You have only 0,1,2,3 indexes for $data array.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is next:**

```
$data = array(
        array("Concepto","Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril"),
        array("Ingresos",100,       100,    100,    100),
        array("Egresos",200,        200,    200,    200),
        array("Deudores",300,       300,    300,    300),
        );
        $aa = array("Saldo",($data[1][1]-$data[2][1]),($data[1][2]-$data[2][2]),($data[1][3]-$data[2][3]),$data[1][4]-$data[2][4]);
        array_push($data,$aa);
```

Now your `$data` array have 5 sub-arrays, and when you call  `$data[5][1]` will be an error because `$data[4]` will be last sub-array. Probably you need

```
$bb = array("Saldo Acumulado",(5000)+($data[1][1])-$data[2][1],
            $data[4][1] + $data[1][2] - $data[2][2],
            "3",
            "4");
array_push($data,$bb) ;
```

Comment: @Vohyndra Where are you getting the idea that it must be 4800 to be correct?

Comment: @sergio the operation is saldo acumulado de enero4900 + ingresos de febrero 100 - egresos de febrero 200  = 4800

Comment: @Daedalus sorry..... 4900 is the value of saldo acumulado of enero i have to add that value to the ingreso of febrero and substract the result to egresos febrero

Comment: @Vohyndra I don't speak whatever language that is.

Comment: Ill tranlate it to english so everyone could understand

Answer (score 0):

Given comments, it becomes obvious where you went wrong with your math.  But before I get to that.. normally [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are zero-indexed.. meaning the first item starts at zero, and it counts up from there.  Thus, your `$data[5][1] + $data[1][2] - $data[2][2]` would error out, given there is no such element in the given array.

Secondly, to your main question....

The math done on

```
$data[4][1] + $data[1][2] - $data[2][2]
 //   ^ correct digit here by the way
```

Would never equal the number you state it would equal, given the values of your array.  However, given your question, I'm going to assume you're actually talking about this bit of math:

```
(5000)+($data[1][1])-$data[2][1]
```

You said the above should equal 4800, but mathematically, this is impossible.  Later, in the comments, you state that your math starts with the number 4900.. and thus the error becomes clear.  Change the 5000 to 4900, and it should work according to your design.  Of course, you should also fix how your array is accessed, given there is no 5 index(it would be 4, and here I am repeating myself).

Comment: Let me fix what you are telling me and give it a try thanks @Daedalus